# Accidentally created VB.NET project instead of C#

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

This should seem simple enough, but can't figure it out.

I was porting a project out of MonoDevelop and into VS2008, but I accidently created the project as VB.NET instead of C#. Now ReSharper and any syntax highlighting is throwing a fit because it's trying to validate it as VB.

How do I tell it to treat it as a C# project without creating a whole new one?

Comment: What speaks against re-creating the project?

Comment: Nothing. I had just assumed it would be more trivial to switch language. Like a project setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# projects and VB.NET projects are so fundamentally different that treating a VB.NET project as a C# project basically would be re-creating the project.  I think you just have to re-create the project from the existing files using the "New" => "Project from Existing Code" command in Visual Studio's File menu.

Answer (score -1):

Try to rename the project file to .csproj.